# Amend order of core listeners

Tags: php, symfony

**TL;DR**
Can you set priority of core Symfony listeners so that `GuardAuthenticationListener` will fire *before* `RouterListener`?

--

I have a legacy app and symfony 'microkernel' app sitting side by side, although both are intertwined some what, in that the symfony app needs to use bits from the legacy app at some points and now for the first time I need to call some symfony things from the legacy app.

Before I go in to detail on this here is some background reading on the set up http://jenko.me/legacy/2016/02/03/an-escape-route-from-legacy-with-stackphp-and-the-symfony-microkernel/

So I'm migrating the security aspect of the legacy app over to Symfony, all in all this hasn't been too bad, largely in part to techniques outlined in this blog post http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-using-advanced-request-matchers-to-activate-firewalls/ and the blog post I mentioned earlier. For URL based access control this is all working sweet.

There are places in the legacy code though where I need to call an `isGranted()` call to check if user has permissions. This is all working fine if the route exists in the Symfony app, i.e. it's gone through the Symfony lifecycle and all listeners have fired.

Where my problem lies is that when the app has a route which *doesn't* exist in the symfony app (i.e. it falls through to the legacy app) by throwing a `NotFoundException` in the `RouterListener` then other listeners (such as the security listener required to create a token for the user) don't fire.

So, **TL;DR** I was wondering if you can change the priority order of core listeners. In my case I would like the security listener (in particular `GuardAuthenticationListener` to fire before the `RouterListener`.

There is a workaround which is to add *all* routes in the symfony app, even if they aren't handled, doing so at least allows all the listeners to fire and thus give me the token I need for my `isGranted` checks.

Comment: Just an FYI: If you absolutely have to do something like this to make your application work, then in 99.9 % cases you have a fundamentally wrong design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so was thinking more about my 'workaround' and I can use that as probably a better approach. So I added this to my routing..

```
catch_all:
    path: /{route}
    requirements:
        route: .*
```

So all routes will get caught in my Symfony app and thus go through the listener dance and eventually fall through to legacy app if not handled. Bonza.